# Highlight multiple records in a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Working with `SQL Server 2008`.

```
fromdate    todate     ID   name
--------------------------------
1-Aug-16    7-Aug-16    x   jack
3-Aug-16    4-Aug-16    x   jack
5-Aug-16    6-Aug-16    x   tom
1-Aug-16    2-Aug-16    x   john
3-Aug-16    4-Aug-16    x   harry
5-Aug-16    6-Aug-16    x   mac
```

Is there a way to script this so that I know if there are multiple names tagged to an `ID` in the `same date range`?

For example above, I want to flag that ID `x` has Name `Jack` and `Tom` tagged in the same date range.

```
ID  multiple_flag
------------------------------------------------
x   yes
y   no
```

Comment: What do you mean about same date range? Give more sample data please.

Comment: please post expected result

Answer (score 0):

If there is a unique index in your table (in my example it is column `i` but you could also generate one by means of using `ROW_NUMBER()`) then you can do the following query based on an `INNER JOIN` to find overlapping date ranges:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (i int identity primary key,fromdate date,todate date,ID int,name varchar(32));
insert into #tmp (fromdate,todate,ID ,name) values
('1-Aug-16','7-Aug-16',3,'jack'),
('3-Aug-16','4-Aug-16',3,'tom'),
('5-Aug-16','6-Aug-16',3,'jack');

select a.*,b.name bname,b.i i2 from #tmp a 
INNER join #tmp b on b.id=a.id AND b.i<>a.i
                    AND (   b.fromdate between a.fromdate and a.todate 
                         OR b.todate between a.fromdate and a.todate)
```

(My id column is `int`). This will give you:

```
i fromdate   todate    ID name bname i2 
- ---------- ---------- - ---- ----- -- 
1 2016-08-01 2016-08-07 3 jack tom   2  
1 2016-08-01 2016-08-07 3 jack jack  3
```

Implement further filtering or grouping as required. I left a little demo [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/520110/find-overlapping-date-regions).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below sql, but it might not be the optimal one..

```
SELECT formdate,todate,id,tab1.name,
case when tab2.#Of >1 then 'yes' else 'no' end as multiple_flag
FROM tab1
inner join (SELECT Name, COUNT(*) as #Of
FROM tab1
GROUP BY Name) as tab2 on tab1.name=tab2.name
order by tab1.id ;
```

add your `where` condition, before the `order by`, if you need to add some date range on your sql.
change `formdate` to `fromdate` before run this sql, as I have used `formdate` in my machine.

The result looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using `EXISTS` `CASE`:

Please note this part of the query:

```
-- make sure the records date ranges overlap
AND t1.fromdate <= t2.todate 
AND t2.fromdate <= t1.todate
```

for an explanation on testing for overlapping ranges, read the [overlap](/questions/tagged/overlap) wiki.

Create and populate sample data (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T as table
(
    fromdate date,
    todate date,
    ID char(1),
    name varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('2016-08-01', '2016-08-07', 'x', 'jack'),
('2016-08-03', '2016-08-04', 'x', 'tom'),
('2016-08-05', '2016-08-06', 'x', 'jack'),
('2016-08-01', '2016-08-02', 'y', 'john'),
('2016-08-03', '2016-08-04', 'y', 'harry'),
('2016-08-05', '2016-08-06', 'y', 'mac')
```

The query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT id, 
    CASE WHEN  EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM @T t2
            WHERE t1.Id = t2.Id
            -- make sure it's not the same record
            AND t1.fromdate <> t2.fromdate 
            AND t1.todate <> t2.todate 
            -- make sure the records date ranges overlap
            AND t1.fromdate <= t2.todate 
            AND t2.fromdate <= t1.todate
        )
    THEN 'Yes' 
    ELSE 'No'
    END  As multiple_flag
FROM @T t1
```

Results:

```
id   multiple_flag
---- -------------
x    Yes
y    No
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, newbie here so I shall take care and edit my questions accordingly.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Comment: Zohar - thanks a lot but I edited my question as well, if you see. Again, apologies. Don't know if this changes the code substantially.                              DECLARE  @T as table
(
    fromdate date,
    todate date,
    ID char(1),
    name varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('2016-08-01', '2016-08-07', 'x', 'jack'),
('2016-08-03', '2016-08-04', 'x', 'tom'),
('2016-08-05', '2016-08-06', 'x', 'jack'),
('2016-08-01', '2016-08-02', 'y', 'john'),
('2016-08-03', '2016-08-04', 'y', 'harry'),
('2016-08-05', '2016-08-06', 'y', 'mac')

Comment: Essentially, for the 'ID' x, I have two 'name' i.e. Jack & Tom in overlapping date ranges.

Comment: Ok, but the result is still the same as the expected result, so I don't think that changes much.